# Searching Algorithm (better than linear)

Tags: java

I have to write a method which returns true if three 3s are present in an integer array(provided they are not consecutive).
I have written this code here: However, it is returning true (which it should not do). Can someone point out my mistake?
arr[]={{4,3,5,2,3,3};

Also, this is a linear algorithm. Can it be done better?

```
public static boolean consecutiveThree(int[] arr) {
        int x=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++) {

            if((arr[i]!=3 && arr[i+1]==3) || (arr[i]==3 && arr[i+1]!=3)) {
                x++;
                //continue;

            }

            if(x==3)
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your approach. What's wrong with iterating through the array and keeping track with an external counter, then checking if that counter is exactly three? Right now you're doing some weird next-item access...

Comment: Your algorithm is checking the same 3 two times.

Comment: Please show the content of arr[].

Comment: `23232` leaves `x == 4`, `2323` leave `x == 3` and `323` leaves `x == 2` I suggest you try stepping through the code in your debugger with some test examples.

Comment: Why shouldn't it return true? `arr[]={{4,3,5,2,3,3}` has three 3s and they are not consecutive.

Comment: They are consecutive as there mustn‘t any 3 directly follow another. So 3, 3 is already consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> returns true if **three 3s are present** in an integer array(provided they are **not consecutive**)

I interpret that as having at least three 3s, and no two 3s are adjacent.

```
public static boolean hasThreeNonconsecutiveThrees(int... values) {
    int count = 0, streak = 0;
    for (int value : values) {
        if (value != 3)
            streak = 0;
        else if (++streak == 2)
            return false; // Found two consecutive (adjacent) 3s
        else
            count++;
    }
    return (count >= 3);
}
```

*Test*

```
    System.out.println(hasThreeNonconsecutiveThrees(4,3,5,2,3,3)); // false
    System.out.println(hasThreeNonconsecutiveThrees(4,3,5,3,2,3)); // true
    System.out.println(hasThreeNonconsecutiveThrees(1,2,3,4,3));   // false
    System.out.println(hasThreeNonconsecutiveThrees(4,3,5,3,3,3)); // false
```

*Output*

```
false
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 1):

At worst case the correct array will end with `... 3 3 X 3`. Unless the array is somewhat sorted or somewhat special you will have to look at every single element to reach the last three 3s. If the array is random, you need linear complexity since you have to review every single element in the array.

Comment: One use case could be:{3,3,2,3,1,3,1}, even thought the first two threes are consecutive, either first or second 3 in array is not consecutive to the other threes. My code is not taking care of this,This should also return true.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is not checking the whether `arr[i-1]` is ***'3'***. That is your algorithm's  mistake.

Try this:-

```
public static boolean consecutiveThree(int[] arr) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] == 3) {
            if (i == 0) { // zero 'th element do not have arr[i-1].
               if(arr[i + 1] != 3) {
                x++;
               }
            } else if (i == arr.length - 1) { // last element do not have arr[i+1].
               if((arr[i - 1] != 3)) {
                x++;
               }
            } else if ((arr[i + 1] != 3) && (arr[i - 1] != 3)) {
                x++;
            }
        }

        if (x == 3) // may be x >= 3
            return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is returning false.

Comment: what do you expect..? for which test case..?

Comment: @anoopknor: what if the first element is not 3?

Comment: that dose not matter .

Comment: Version 1 of answer returns false for `4,3,5,3,2,3`.

Comment: Version 2 throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6` for `4,3,5,2,3,3` as edited by @rm-rf, so rolling that back.

Comment: @Andreas : I hope that shouldn't.

Comment: @rm-rf Version 4 throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6` for `4,3,5,2,3,3`

Comment: @rm-rf `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` for `3` --- And returns true for `3,5,3,2,3,1,3,3`

Comment: Uff ! @Andreas : Thanks a lot for pointing out ! I'll correct it !

Comment: @Andreas : This should be the right code. Have handled the edge cases properly now :-)

Comment: @rm-rf No you haven't. I don't even need to run it to see that. You still do `arr[i + 1]` without checking if `i` is too big for that. You also simply ignore adjacent 3s, but result should be false if there are *any* adjacent 3s.

Comment: @Andreas : Yeah, I made the mistake of checking if  `i` is capable to compare between with its adjacent elements (ie; proper handling for edge elements in array was not done previously). Have corrected it now :-)